# How to Convert Integer Number to 12 Digit Number in PHP

Tags: php

I need to convert price to 12 digit number for bank payment gateway process

Example: 25.00 convert to 000000002500

how to do that

i keep price in integer format in database.

Thanks

Comment: Multiply the the example by 100 or remove the . then use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) ? This question has been asked on Stackoverflow a lot and I recommend next time you do some better research

Comment: Hint: `str_pad(25.00*100 ,12 ,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php) function to do that, e. g.:

```
$printvalue = sprintf("%012d", $intvalue);
```

To print the price as the OP asked, you set `$intvalue` to an integer, as:

```
$intvalue = $decimalvalue * 100;
$printvalue = sprintf("%012d", $intvalue);
```

Comment: Fast and Nice one.+1

Comment: It not include decimal

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. Added